# disable js function if css class is applied to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple html elements like

```
 <a class="myInput black" ng-click="DoSomething(1)">1</a>
 <a class="myInput silver" ng-click="DoSomething(2)">2</a>
 ...
 <a class="myInput white" ng-click="DoSomething(10)">10</a>
```

on click DoSomething function besides other stuff add css class to clicked element

```
<a class="myInput black selectedElement" ng-click="DoSomething(1)">1</a>
```

how can I using javascript disable or remove DoSomething js function if that element has applied selectedElement css class.

Comment: appears to be angular `ng-click`. If so question is backwards, what determines class on elements? Should be driven by data model not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, But it should work.

```
function DoSomething(ele,i) {
ele.removeAttribute("ng-click");
//do whatever you were doing with 'i'
}
```

and anchor should look like

```
<a class="myInput black" ng-click="DoSomething(this,1)">1</a>
```

Comment: `ng-click` is not a native  event ... `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: i haven''t worked with angularjs.. so help edit this answer

Comment: how would removing an attribute prevent an event that already occurred anyway? Also how does this do any class matching?